# I was doing Flutter app development in Android Studio, and I got an error in the Android build. Record how to resolve this issue

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

【Flutter】e: Class ‘SoundStreamPlugin’ is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun onRequestPermissionsResult/e: ‘onRequestPermissionsResult’ overrides nothing
The error message is as follows: (Split for better viewing)

```
e: /Users/UserName/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sound_stream-0.3.0/android/src/main/kotlin/vn/casperpas/sound_stream/SoundStreamPlugin.kt: (45, 8): Class 'SoundStreamPlugin' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun onRequestPermissionsResult(p0: Int, p1: Array<(out) String!>, p2: IntArray): Boolean defined in io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.RequestPermissionsResultListener
e: /Users/UserName/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sound_stream-0.3.0/android/src/main/kotlin/vn/casperpas/sound_stream/SoundStreamPlugin.kt: (182, 5): 'onRequestPermissionsResult' overrides nothing
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sound_stream:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                           2,093ms
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

/Users/UserName/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sound_stream-0.3.0/android/src/main/kotlin/vn/casperpas/sound_stream/SoundStreamPlugin.kt を開きます。

And look for onRequestPermissionsResult().

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>?, grantResults: IntArray?): Boolean {
  when (requestCode) {
    audioRecordPermissionCode -> {
      if (grantResults != null) {
        permissionToRecordAudio = grantResults.isNotEmpty() &&
          grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
      }
      completeInitializeRecorder()
      return true
    }
  }
  return false
}
```

The argument in this '?' Delete.

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray): Boolean {
```

Again, build on Android.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an error from the [sound_stream](https://pub.dev/packages/sound_stream) package itself. According to an issue posted [here](https://github.com/CasperPas/flutter-sound-stream/issues/54#issue-1268338357), there are some errors that have to do with null safety for flutter 3.0.1. check the solution posted there if it works for you, edit the package yourself. if it doesn't then I guess you will have to wait until the developer fixes it.